# How can I recover my Gmail user name if I only have my cell number?

Tags: gmail, account-management, google-account

How can I recover my Gmail user name if I only have my cell number? I've created a Gmail account only to be able to create a Facebook account. I had to reload Facebook on my phone but I need my Gmail username and login as I have located my account on Facebook but the FB password reset code I need my Gmail username. Is there a way the this can be send to me on an alternative E-mail or to my cellphone number that I use for this account?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery
2. Choose lost username
3. Enter recovery email (if you don't know what was it, try testing all of your other email ids)

This is the only way you can get your id back. That's why Gmail is secure. Phone number is used only for authentication, not for recovery process.