# Gmail password reset sent to phone number I no longer own or access

Tags: gmail

I am able to access my Gmail account on my Android, but I want to access it using my laptop. I can't do that because I don't know my password and when I go to reset it, it asks me to input the phone number associated with the account.

The problem is that I no longer have that phone number. What can I do to reset my Gmail password?

Comment: Does http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50194/how-can-i-recover-my-gmail-user-name-if-i-only-have-my-cell-number help?

Answer (score 1):

This links help you to reset Gmail password:

[Change your password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6567?hl=en)

[Having trouble signing in?](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/)

[How-To-Reset-My-Gmail-Password](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=El0xTW_qd3c)